# kendo grid in IE11

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, internet-explorer-11

I am testing kendo grid with **IE 11** and stumbling on a bug.

Basically the grid click acts differently in various version of kendo library.

In the latest version i.e 2013.2.918 grid click is triggered twice.
and the grid click does not work all the way back until version 2012.3.1114.

here is the plunker link.
http://plnkr.co/edit/MgkSCf2vqBfYehtGvKUx?p=preview

I would be happy if i get a patch for it in any of the kendo versions.

Thanks
Sush

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems caused by the `alert`. Changing it to `console.log` doesn't cause double mouse event firing.